# Getting bind variable names in ref cursor output of oracle function

Tags: oracle

I have written oracle function with ref cursor as return type.

Function returns the correct output but it adds character at the beginning and end.

At the beginning, it adds something like {<substr(:B3,:B2,:B1)=

And at the end, it adds, >,}

Can anyone please help me to understand this?

Thanks

Comment: Show some code so people could review what can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I presume it is about Oracle SQL Developer tool, as it shows such a result.

There's nothing wrong, nothing's being added in real resultset - you just don't know how to properly see it.

Here's an example of what I think:

1. create a function, select from it
2. result looks as you described; now **double-click** the result and you'll see the pencil icon in the right-hand side of the result cell
3. now click that pencil icon - a new window will open, showing "nice" result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. it helped. But is there any setting or something which can be done to avoid it from display?

Comment: There's none, as far as I can tell.